# Query multiple tables in MySQL with Dynamic query

Tags: mysql, dynamic, datatable

I am trying to create a dynamic query from tables that are stored in an old MySQL database (ver4.1). Orders are archived in separate table for each month, with the format

```
ordtbl_YYYY_MMM (ordtbl_2019_M01 / ordtbl_2019_M02... etc)
```

Each table contains the same fields, and querying one of these tables is of course relatively easy. 
How can I set this to become more dynamic? If the user can enter a date range, I can parse the year and month from those parameters, but how then make sure I am collecting the orders from the correct tables? It might span 2,3 or more tables depending on the date range requested by the user, i.e. all orders from Jan 1st -> July 3rd, I would need to union the results from 7 tables.

Comment: Why not copy all the data from the periodic tables in to a single "master" table with a date column, problem solved.

Comment: Build a stored procedure which loops through all possible months and years and build a Sql statement with all Selects unioned. Problem is mysql doens't like when you make a Select, when the table doesn't exist., so you gave ti test first.

Comment: Yes. Build a new table with all the old data, and partition it in accordance with best practice, if necessary

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the underlying structure of the database, and create a single master table with all of the data. Another issue is that tables are created as the new month starts, i.e. on the 1st July, a new "archived" table appears in the data set with ordtbl_2019_M07.
I wondering if there is a way to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the correct table set, then somehow loop through these....

Comment: *"Yes. Build a new table with all the old data, and partition it in accordance with best practice, if necessary"* @Strawberry  MySQL (version 4.1) is to legacy so partition is not really a option..

Comment: *"I wondering if there is a way to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the correct table set, then somehow loop through these.... "* i wonder why you don't upgrade to a more modern version.. Even mysql.com is not showing the MySQL 4+ documention annymore..   And iam pretty sure the `information_schema` database is a MySQL 5+ thing, i think the best thing which MySQL 4 supports to get metadata is `SHOW`

Comment: No chance of upgrading or modifying....the MySQL version is linked to an ERP Mission Critical system which we cannot touch....